# Prevent scaffolding of certain views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4scaffolding

I have customized the controller and a couple of views using T4 in MVC and no longer need the Details and Delete views. How do I prevent Visual Studio from scaffolding these views out when I scaffold out the controller and other views?
Thanks!